# Given a parabola with equation $y=ax^2+bx+c$ which has as a tip the point $(3, 1)$ and passes through $(2, 0)$. Find out the product $abc$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, analytic-geometry, problem-solving

Given a parabola with equation $y=ax^2+bx+c$ which has as a tip the point $(3, 1)$ and passes through $(2, 0)$. Find out the product $abc$.

I can't solve the question. I am trying to solve it with the use of analytic geometry on parabolas, but it isn't working out for me. I have that $x=-\frac{b}{2a}$ is a tip. Hence $y=\frac{b^2}{4a}-\frac{b^2}{2a}+c$. I don't know how to finish it off from here. I assume we need to get an expression of the form of $abc=...$ but I haven't managed to get that. Could you please explain to me how to solve it?

Comment: Even if you cannot solve the problem, please show the own tries. For instance, the two given condition have easy translations as algebraic equations, which are these equations?

Comment: ok @dan_fulea editing it now

Comment: OK, we already have an answer with some hints... Just to have other hints here... Solve $$\left\{ \begin{aligned} 3 &= -\frac b{2a}\\1 &= 9a + 3b + c\\0 &= 4a + 2b + c\end{aligned}\right.$$

Comment: @dan_fulea I've edited it, also thanks for the hints, I'm working on them now

Comment: nice one @dan_fulea I've worked it out now thanks to your hint, thank you very much. The way I worked it out is as follows:

$b=-6a$

$1=-9a+c$

$-8a+c=0$

Hence $a=1$, $b=-6$, $c=8$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

1. Prove that if $y=ax^2+bx+c$, then it's "tip point" is at $x=-\dfrac{b}{2a}$.
2. Prove that if a curve passes through a point, then it satisfies the equation of the curve.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no $xy$ term in the equation, the parabola has axes parallel to coordinate axes. Specifically, it is just the parabola $y=Ax^2$ translated (no rotation).

The new vertex is $(3,1)$ instead of $(0,0)$. Hence the equation of parabola is
$$(y-1)=A(x-3)^2$$

$A$ can be obtained by using that $(2,0)$ lies on parabola whence $a,b,c$ can be found.